# IOS 8.x homescreen webapp crash at window.location

Tags: javascript, html, ios8

We have an HTML5 webapp running from the homescreen on an IOS8.x device. The app crashes sometimes as the user is directed to another page by using the window.location line. The app worked perfectly fine on IOS7.x. The strange thing is that we have several lines in our code with window.location that works fine, except for the one line where the app crashes to the homescreen. Anyone here on this forum with a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the HTML5 video tag from the page.

That prevents the webapp from crashing when redirecting via JS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed it was the video tag that made the webapp crash. We removed it, and the webapp works again on an IOS8.x device. As a consequence, we have no sound. Is there a way to have sound working in a webapp on an IOS8.x device?